# UITableView scrolling issues

Tags: xcode, image, uitableview, scroll

In my app i am using a table view to display images .I am displaying 4 images in a row.I am able to display the images nicely.But my issue is that when i scroll the table view to view the images then the scrolling takes place at a very slow speed and also it gets stuck in between.What could be the reason.I am posting my part of code here ,please help.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@" numberOfRowsInSection :%d",(int)ceil([wordsInSentence count]/4.0)]);
    buttonIndex=1;

    return (int)ceil([wordsInSentence count]/4.0);
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 

    if (cell!=nil) {
      cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
      //return cell;

    }
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    for (int i=0; i < 4; i++) {
      UIImageView *importMediaSaveImage;
      NSString *name1;
      NSString *name2;
      NSString *name3;
      NSString *name4;

      switch (i) {

       case 0:
        importMediaSaveImage = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25+90*(i%4), 6, 85, 125)] autorelease] ;
        if([wordsInSentence count]>((indexPath.row * 4)+ 0)){

           name1= [wordsInSentence objectAtIndex:((indexPath.row * 4)+ 0)]; 

           importMediaSaveImage.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name1 ofType:@"png" inDirectory:@"Images"]];
           buttonIndex=((indexPath.row * 4)+ 0)+1;
           [self showImage:importMediaSaveImage];
           [imageViewArray addObject:importMediaSaveImage];
           [cell.contentView addSubview:importMediaSaveImage];  
           [imageCollection addObject:importMediaSaveImage];
           NSLog(name1);
        } else {
           importMediaSaveImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"White.png"];
           //importMediaSaveImage.image = nil;
           [cell.contentView setHidden:YES];
        }

        break;

      case 1:
        importMediaSaveImage = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25+90*(i%4), 6, 85, 125)] autorelease] ;
        if([wordsInSentence count]>((indexPath.row * 4)+ 1)){
          name2 = [wordsInSentence objectAtIndex:((indexPath.row * 4)+ 1)];     
          NSLog(name2);
          importMediaSaveImage.image  = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name2 ofType:@"png" inDirectory:@"Images"]];
          [cell.contentView addSubview:importMediaSaveImage];
          buttonIndex=((indexPath.row * 4)+ 1)+1;
          [self showImage:importMediaSaveImage];
          [imageViewArray addObject:importMediaSaveImage];
          [imageCollection addObject:importMediaSaveImage];
        } else {
          importMediaSaveImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"White.png"];
          //importMediaSaveImage.image = nil;
          [cell.contentView addSubview:importMediaSaveImage];
        }
     break;

    case 2:
        importMediaSaveImage = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25+90*(i%4), 6, 85, 125)] autorelease] ;
        if([wordsInSentence count]>((indexPath.row * 4)+ 2)){
          name3 = [wordsInSentence objectAtIndex:((indexPath.row * 4)+ 2)]; 
          NSLog(name3);
          importMediaSaveImage.image  = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name3 ofType:@"png" inDirectory:@"Images"]];
          [cell.contentView addSubview:importMediaSaveImage];
          buttonIndex=((indexPath.row * 4)+ 2)+1;
          [self showImage:importMediaSaveImage];
          [imageViewArray addObject:importMediaSaveImage];
          [imageCollection addObject:importMediaSaveImage];
        } else {
          importMediaSaveImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"White.png"];
          //importMediaSaveImage.image = nil;
          [cell.contentView addSubview:importMediaSaveImage];
        }
        break;

    case 3:
        importMediaSaveImage = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25+90*(i%4), 6, 85, 125)] autorelease] ;
        if([wordsInSentence count]>((indexPath.row * 4)+ 3)){
          [cell.contentView addSubview:importMediaSaveImage];   
          name4 = [wordsInSentence objectAtIndex:((indexPath.row * 4)+ 3)];
          NSLog(name4);
          importMediaSaveImage.image  = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name4 ofType:@"png" inDirectory:@"Images"]];
          buttonIndex=((indexPath.row * 4)+ 3)+1;
          [self showImage:importMediaSaveImage];
          [imageViewArray addObject:importMediaSaveImage];
          [imageCollection addObject:importMediaSaveImage];
        } else {
          importMediaSaveImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"White.png"];
          //importMediaSaveImage.image = nil;
          [cell.contentView addSubview:importMediaSaveImage];
        }
        break;

    } //switch end
  } //for loop end

  return cell;
}
```

Comment: Look at [this] (http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/uitableview-2/)

Comment: I'm using a table view to load multiple images in a row. but when i scroll the table view the table view crashes or overlaps

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem you have is that you are doing all of the rendering inside the -cellForRowAtIndexPath method. This works fine for text and quickly iterated data, but for images or data loaded from the web it is terribly inefficient.

Keep in mind, this method is called once for each cell visible on the screen. So if you have a lot of processor intensive stuff going on, it is going to make scrolling lag or crash.

You should read this article on [Fast Scrolling](http://blog.atebits.com/2008/12/fast-scrolling-in-tweetie-with-uitableview/) written by Loren Brichter of Tweetie fame. It explains how to achieve fast scrolling out of a tableview with lots of information. It is a little dated for iOS 4 as some of the methods have changed, but it close enough to get you going in the right direction.